# Remove columns from CSV

Tags: regex, database, csv, notepad++

I don't know anything about Notepad++ Regex.

This is the data I have in my CSV:

```
6454345|User1-2ds3|62562012032|324|148|9c1fe63ccd3ab234892beaf71f022be2e06b6cd1
3305611|User2-42g563dgsdbf|22023001345|0|0|c36dedfa12634e33ca8bc0ef4703c92b73d9c433  
8749412|User3-9|xgs|f|98906504456|1534|51564|411b0fdf54fe29745897288c6ad699f7be30f389
```

How can I use a Regex to remove the 5th and 6th column? The numbers in the 5th and 6th column are variable in length.

Another problem is the User row can also contain a |, to make it even worse.

I can use a macro to fix this, but the file is a few millions lines long.

This is the final result I want to achieve:

```
6454345|User1-2ds3|62562012032|9c1fe63ccd3ab234892beaf71f022be2e06b6cd1
3305611|User2-42g563dgsdbf|22023001345|c36dedfa12634e33ca8bc0ef4703c92b73d9c433
8749412|User3-9|xgs|f|98906504456|411b0fdf54fe29745897288c6ad699f7be30f389
```

I am open for suggestions on how to do this with another program, command line utility, either Linux or Windows.

Comment: By which logic does `User1-2ds3` become `User2-42g563dgsdbf`, and `User2-9xg|s` become `User2-9|xgs`?

Comment: @trincot Badly copy/pasting and editing the lines afterwards. I've fixed the example now.

Comment: `User row can also contain a | ` Yeah, if the pipe is the delimiter, unless it's escaped in the field, it can't be differentiated with the delimiter. That means, _no solution_.  Sorry ...

Comment: This would be a malformed CSV since not all rows have equal number of columns. Depending on what you are loading it into, it may or may not work.

Comment: Also, the _columns_ affected, according to your before/after are the 4th and 5th (not 5 and 6).

Comment: `use a Regex to remove the 5th and 6th column` Yet you've accepted a solution that is _End_ oriented ... removes the `|col|col`|col<end>` from the end which is not the 5th and 6th column from the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match `\|[^|]+\|[^|]+(\|[^|]+$)`

Repalce `$1`

Basically, Anchor to the end of the line, and remove columns [-1] and [-2] (I assume columns can't be empty. Replace `+` with `*` if they can)

If you need finer detail then that, I'd recommend writing a Java or Python script to manual parse and rewrite the file for you.

Comment: @Austin_Anderson Actually, in Notepad++ (at least my version) both forms work. I prefer the $ form because it is more standard.

Comment: what do you know, it works! I must have tested that on an old version the last time I checked.

Answer (score 1):

I've captured three groups and given them names. If you use a replace utility like `sed` or `vimregex`, you can replace `remove` with nothing. Or you can use a programming language to concatenate `keep_before` and `keep_after` for the desired result.

```
^(?<keep_before>(?:[^|]+\|){3})(?<remove>(?:[^|]+\|){2})(?<keep_after>.*)$
```

You may have to remove the group namings and use `\1` etc. instead, depending on what environment you use.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aGVNR2/1)

Answer (score 1):

From Notepad++ hit `ctrl + h` then enter the following in the dialog:

Find what: `\|\d+\|\d+(\|[0-9a-z]+)$`

Replace with: `$1`

Search mode: `Regular Expression`

Click **replace** and done.

**Regex Explain:**

`\|\d+` : match 1st string that starts with | followed by number

`\|\d+` : match 2nd string that starts with | followed by number

`(\|[0-9a-z]+)`: match and capture the string after the 2nd number.

`$` : This is will force regex search to match the end of the string.

**Replacement:**

`$1` : replace the found string with whatever we have between the captured group which is whatever we have between the parentheses `(\|[0-9a-z]+)`